# How to Ruby on Rails authentication with LDAP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ldap

I'm developing a web app and I have an authentication method using `bcrypt gem`It works fine, but I wanted to change the authentication method to LDAP because I'm using an intranet environment and want my users to be able to sign in with windows credentials.

I'm looking to use `net-ldap gem` but I can't find any good toturials/explanations online on how to implement this into my web application.

- Can you help me with this?
- How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a utility class I've used in the past to do multi-server LDAP check:

```
require 'net/ldap'

# Ldap.authenticate('user', 'password')
# => `true` if valid
# => `false` if invalid
# => `nil` if LDAP unavailable

class Ldap
  def self.config
    {
      domain: 'mydomain',
      servers: ['server1', 'server2']
    }
  end

  def self.authenticate(login, pass)
    return false if login.empty? or pass.empty?
    config['servers'].each do |server|
      auth = authenticate_against_server(login, pass, server, config['domain'])
      return auth unless auth.nil?
    end
    nil
  end

 private

  def self.authenticate_against_server(login, pass, host, domain)
    conn = Net::LDAP.new(
      host:       host,
      port:       636,
      base:       "dc=#{domain}, dc=local",
      encryption: :simple_tls,
      auth:       { username: "#{login}@#{domain}.local",
                    password: pass,
                    method: :simple }
    )
    Timeout::timeout(15) do
      return conn.bind ? true : false
    end
  rescue Net::LDAP::LdapError => e
    notify_ldap_admin(host, 'Error', e)
    return nil
  rescue Timeout::Error => e
    notify_ldap_admin(host, 'Timeout', e)
    return nil
  end

  def self.notify_ldap_admin(host, error_type, error)
    msg = "LDAP #{error_type} on #{host}"
    RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.debug(msg)
    DeveloperMailer.deliver_ldap_failure_msg(msg, error)
  end
end
```

Comment: Where do I put this in my application or how do I implement/use this in my application? I'm fairly new to Rails and this is my first application and I feel a bit lost in this "field"

Comment: It doesn't really matter much, as Rails autoloads just about everything, so classes are available app-wide. `/app/models/ldap.rb` or `app/models/concerns/ldap.rb` seem appropriate to me.

Comment: can you explain me what do I need to replace in your code in order for mine to work?

Comment: Domain and Hostnames or IP addresses for the servers in `self.config`, and possibly anything in the `Net::LDAP.new` call (but probably not unless you have a nonstandard config). Your domain admin should know more if you have trouble with these settings.

Comment: and then what do I do so this authenticates users on my webapp login

Comment: That depends on what your existing authentication system does. At whatever point it checks the password is valid, you should be able to replace with `Ldap.authenticate(login, pass)`.  If you are looking to roll your own solution, check out these links: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login

Answer (score 0):

If you're fairly new, I'd avoid homebrewing authentication.  Check out either

- Devise w/ LDAP: https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable
- Omniauth w/ LDAP: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-ldap

I started with Devise, and still use it for a few projects, but Omniauth is super powerful and more versatile in my opinion.  You have to do more yourself though.

Further reading should include [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) for authorization within your app, unless everybody gets everything that is.

Comment: I dislike using devise and I'm avoiding it, I'll look into omniauth !