# Rails LDAP Invalid Credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently working on implementing an LDAP signin for users within my business.

```
require 'net/ldap'
ldap = Net::LDAP.new(:host => '10.0.0.32', :port => 389)
if ldap.bind(:method => :simple, :username => "ttyler",
             :password => "********")
  # authentication succeeded
else
  # authentication failed
  p ldap.get_operation_result
end
```

This code is running however I am getting the error below.

```
#<OpenStruct extended_response=nil, code=49, error_message="80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1\u0000", matched_dn="", message="Invalid Credentials">
```

My current machine is on the domain that my business belongs to and I did a `nslookup` to make sure the host was correct - it is. I know my credentials are not wrong because I use them all day everybody. Does anybody know why this would be happening?

I tried the name of the domain as well which is ********.local and that did not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: When you log on, you likely don't just logon to a server, but to a domain. You may need to supply a `base` parameter string, and maybe other options. This thread shows a util class I've used successfully: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45015896/23915

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the :base attribute with your domain name.
f.e. if your domain is example.local, then your base is "dc=example,dc=com".

You also need to specify the full path of your user in the directory.
f.e. the server administrator is usually "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local".

A regular user is generally found in the Users ou such as: "cn=ttyler,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com".