# Authenticate rails 6 app with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails - 6.0.2
Ruby - 2.6.6

I want to authenticate devise rails app with Active Directory login credentials.

My requirement is: Once the user logs in to the system, go to the application in the browser. Click on a link "Authenticate with AD", the user should automatically log in to the application without any login credentials.

Any suggestions ?

Few questions. These might be very basic, but I am new to AD.

- If the rails production server is in Linux, do we need to join that linux server to the AD server ?
- If yes, what configuration we need to make for that ?
- Will it be at server level configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there be server level configurations. For configuring your server follow this  [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-ruby).

For idap_authenticable gem you can follow this complete [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013354/how-to-ruby-on-rails-authentication-with-ldap).

Yes you would need to join the Linux server because you need to transfer the code to the server. To transfer the code you can use git.

You would need to configure the `database.yml and secret.yml` production:

```
 adapter: sqlite3
 database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Comment: The answer link: so it basically accepts username & password to make a authentication call. But my requirement is not to enter username & password. It automatically log in

Comment: If your requirement is not to enter username & password then the only possible way to do this would be to store the token in your localStorage and when user press login then you can check if the token is valid or invalid. If the token is valid then redirect the application to the homepage otherwise allow user for authentication.

Comment: Hi Rutha, could you please explain a bit on the above about the token. It would be helpful.

Comment: Sure. When the user first logins for the first time into the application you need to store the token in cookies or localStorage. MSAL automatically refresh's the token when the token expires which means after logging in the first time the user will not be unauthorized. When the user attempts to login into your application you can check if the token is valid instead of asking the user for their username/password and then you can simply allow the user to directly go to the home page.

Comment: Hi Rutha, Sorry for the late reply. How would it connect to the AD server & check if the user is logged in?

Comment: const promise = agent.acquireTokenSilent(...)
If the user has not logged in then the permissions will be rejected with the error user_login_error. If the user is still logged in, then the promise will be resolved.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question, that: Its not Azure AD, its basically internal server AD. Will it still work ?